# Problem with custom controller Api-platform

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

My controller doesnt work on GET method but it works on PUT. I dont know why. If anybody have an answer.
I know that in v2.6 there is a difference between operationitems and collectionitems but in v3 there is only operation. I think it must be a syntax problem but I don't know.
I'm asking you the question because I've been looking for the solution for three days and I'm starting to have a headache.
It returns me a 404 error. It does not find the path to the controller.

My entity

```
    namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Delete;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Put;
use App\Controller\CommentaireCountController;
use App\Controller\CommentairePublishController;
use App\Repository\CommentaireRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CommentaireRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(
            openapiContext: [
                'summary' => 'poste ton commentaire'
            ],
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['create:commentaire']]
        ),
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups'=>['read:blabla']]
        ),
        new Put(
            openapiContext: [
                'summary' => 'Remplace un champ de commentaire'
            ],
            denormalizationContext: ['groups'=>['write:commentaire']],
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['create:commentaire']] 
        ),
        new Delete(),
        new Patch(),
    ],
)]
#[Put(
    uriTemplate: '/commentaires/{id}/publish',
    controller: CommentairePublishController::class,
    openapiContext: [
        'summary' => 'Mettre en ligne un commentaire',
        'description' => 'Mettre en ligne le commentaire'
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups'=>['read:commentaire']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups'=>['publish:commentaire']],
    name: 'Publish'
)]
#[Get(
    uriTemplate: '/commentaires/count',
    controller: CommentaireCountController::class,
    name: 'Count'
)]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['id' => 'exact', 'proprietaire.name' => 'iexact'])]
class Commentaire
    {
```

My countcontroller

```
    namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Commentaire;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[AsController]
class CommentaireCountController
{
    public function __invoke(): int
    {
        return 10;
    }
    }
```

And my working publishcontroller

```
    namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Commentaire;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController]
class CommentairePublishController
{
    public function __invoke(Commentaire $data): Commentaire{
    $data->setOnline(true);
    return $data;
}
    }
```

The ApiPlatform response :
{
"@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
"@type": "hydra:Error",
"hydra:title": "An error occurred",
"hydra:description": "Not Found",
"trace": [
{
"namespace": "",
"short_class": "",
"class": "",
"type": "",
"function": "",
"file": "C:\Users\God\Desktop\Api\api2\vendor\api-platform\core\src\Symfony\EventListener\ReadListener.php",
"line": 94,
"args": []
},

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`GET /commentaires/count` will always call this operation instead the one you expect:

```php
 new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups'=>['read:blabla']]
        ),
```

This option is appearing first so your `count` is consider as one of the `{id}`.

To fix this you need to set requirements for your first Get:

```php
 new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups'=>['read:blabla']],
            requirements: ['id' => '\d+']
        ),
```

After this `GET /commentaires/count` will match this operation:

```php
#[Get(
    uriTemplate: '/commentaires/count',
    controller: CommentaireCountController::class,
    name: 'Count'
)]
```

But you will get another problem. Before calling your `CommentaireCountController:class` it will run a ReadListener which will try to retrieve your resource using built-in provider and it will fail because it doesn't know which resource should be retrieved for `/commentaires/count` .

To fix this disable ReadListener by adding `read: false` to your custom operation like this:

```php
#[Get(
    uriTemplate: '/commentaires/count',
    controller: CommentaireCountController::class,
    name: 'Count',
    read: false
)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the documentation:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#retrieving-the-entity

**Retrieving the Entity:**

> If you want to bypass the automatic retrieval of the entity in your custom operation, you can set `read: false` in the operation attribute:

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem. The reason is that the endpoint name was saved somewhere in the cache, but cache:clear didn't help. I was created the same endpoint with a different name and that solution solved problem. I know that it's not a satisfactory solution, but I'd love to know how to fix it if anyone else comes across this.